# Problem of amsart and microtype under xelatex

Tags: xetex, microtype, amsart

Would anyone know what is the problem of the interaction of amsart and microtype under xelatex -- that does not happen under latex, pdflatex or lualatex?

With the file:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

 \begin{abstract}
    This is a test.
 \end{abstract}
 \end{document}
```

I get the not so clear message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg)
! Bad character code (-815).
<to be read again> 
               h
l.6      \begin{abstract}
```

Comment: with tex live 2016, i get no error message.  everything goes through smoothly, although there is no output.  so presumably this is something that happened with tex live 2017 or later (which i don't have available).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I get the error in tl2017

Comment: If I use pdflatex I get no pdf produced. If I use pdflatex and add some text below the abstract I get that text but no abstract. This is with a fully updated TL2017. If I even remove the loading of microtype there are problems. So things aren't quite right with pdflatex either.

Comment: @HerbSchulz -- in order to get the abstract to print, `amsart` requires the use of `\maketitle`.

Comment: I took the \maketitle line out to make a real MWE ... :)

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer says, this is a bug in `microtype`, which will be fixed in the next version. For now, use Ulrike's workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is imho a bug in microtype. When fontspec is not loaded it retrieve the wrong glyph slots in some cases and this leads to errors. This is not related to amsmart. You would get the same error with article, if you use `\scshape`. I already made a bug report. As a work-around I would advise to load `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

 \begin{abstract}
    This is a test.
 \end{abstract}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a copy of

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg
```

and save it in the directory with your document then comment out  lines 192-196 so it looks like.

```
%    /one.oldstyle   = {100,100},
%    /two.oldstyle   = { 50, 50},
%    /three.oldstyle = { 30, 80},
%    /four.oldstyle  = { 50, 50},
%    /seven.oldstyle = { 50, 80},
```

Then your document runs without error.

Comment: I have no idea why that failed, but you could use this as a pointer  if you raise an issue  with the microtype maintainer

Comment: actually just `%    /two.oldstyle   = { 50, 50},` is sufficient, the other lines are OK

Comment: I'll leave this up as a debugging aid, but you should accept Ulrike's answer